Formal proof that for every function, preimage of empty set is empty set
If we define the inverse of a function $f: A \to B$ as,
$$f^{-1}(x) = \{ y \mid f(y)=x , x \in B\}.$$
And then further extend this for sunsets $S\subset B$ sets,
$$f^{-1}(S) = \{ a\mid f(a)=b , a \in A, b \in S\}.$$
And then set $S= \varnothing$, we have that
$$f^{-1}(\varnothing) = \{ a \mid f(a)= b, a \in A, b\in \varnothing\}.$$
Some proofs I found on the internet follow that $f^{-1}(\varnothing)$ must necessarily be $\varnothing$ again. However, how would I formally take this step?

$u\in\emptyset$ is always false, so $f^{-1}(\emptyset)={x~:~f(x)\in\emptyset}$ is empty. Your definitions 2 and 3 are written incorrectly, or to say the least super-confusingly. Maybe that tricked you.

I believed I fixed this definition. I don't understand what you mean here by always falls @MichalAdamaszek

You did not fix the definition. Why are you writing $S_b$ now? The preimage of $S \subseteq B$ by $f$ is ${a \in A | f(a) \in S}$, or ${a \in A | \exists b \in S. f(a) = b}$. $u \in \emptyset$ is always false, as in $\forall u. \neg(u \in \emptyset)$, by definition of the empty set, so $f^{-1}(\emptyset) = {a \in A | \bot} = \emptyset$.

What is the problem with writing $S_b$? Could you elaborate?

It seems to imply that the set is part of a family indexed by elements of $B$.

Here is a more concise definition: $f^{-1}(S)={a \in A \mid f(a) \in S}$. And it translates more easily into natural language: "The set of all $a$ in $A$ such that $f(a)$ is in $S$".

And then $f^{-1}(\emptyset)={a \in A \mid f(a) \in \emptyset}$. But $f(a) \in \emptyset$ is always false, so...

Do not use \phi for the empty set; that's the Greek letter phi. There are two commands you can use: \emptyset will produce $\emptyset$; and \varnothing will yield $\varnothing$.

Formally, if $f:A\to B$ and $Y\subseteq B$ then
$$f^{-1}(Y)=\{a\in A\ |\ f(a)=b\text{ for some }b\in Y\}$$
or even more formally
$$\phi(a)= \exists b\in Y, f(a)=b$$
$$f^{-1}(Y)=\{a\in A\ |\ \phi(a)\}$$
So what happens if $Y=\emptyset$? The condition "$\exists b\in \emptyset$" cannot be satisfied, and therefore the entire $\phi$ formula is false for any $a\in A$. In fact it is false for any $a$ (not only taken from $A$), which is a subtle but important difference.
Which then implies that the "$a\in f^{-1}(\emptyset)$" sentence is false for any $a$. And that is precisely the definition of the empty set (which as we all know is unique among sets).
